# vba dir function error 5174

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been getting a runtime error 5174.  In the directory there are .docx and .docm files.  I have tried to add .doc files, as I read .docx are not supported by the dir function.  Following adding the file, the code will go through all files in the directory like it should.  If I run it again, it will fail with an error 5174.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
sMyDir = "C:\weekly\" & "*.doc?"
sDocName = Dir(sMyDir)
While sDocName <> ""
Documents.Open FileName:=sDocName, Visible:=False
' Does stuff
sDocName = Dir()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result was the Dir function returns the file name only. So when I used the open method I added the path before the variable which stored the filename. I just needed to read the documentation on the Dir function. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Error 5174 indicates file not found, which means it is possible that the directory is incorrect.  Try using **LIKE**:

```
sMyDir LIKE "C:\weekly\" & "*.doc?"
```

Edit: Your sDocName does not provide with a full path as well

Comment: That gives a syntax error.  I know the path is correct.  Like I said it will run if I add a .doc file in the directory, and also if I don't use the Dir function, and add a file in the path, such as Documents.Open FileName:="C:\weekly\test.docx".  The directory and the files are correct.  The error box is returning the first filename

Comment: @guy you sure the first time works?  Cuz after checking, your sDocName  gives the doc name instead of the full path

Comment: You are correct.  The path the error was returning is the default Documents path, and it failed to work,  I must have changed something when it worked.  I am sure this path exists though, I have copied it from Explorer.

Comment: Is it possible the path is too long?  The real path is like C:\users\myfirstname.lastname\Documents\work\weeklyreports? I moved the files to the Documents directory, and it works as its supposed to.  If so, when I move it in production, the path is longer, so I will have the same problem.

Comment: @guy Is the "\" included in the path's end? like C:\users\myfirstnam....\weeklyreports\.  Or, it could be the permission as well, i.e. you do no have permission the read/write those files.  Now that it works on another path, it's pretty sure the code isn't the issue.  Also I have not encountered path's too long / too deep causing an error.

Comment: I will have to check in the morning. Left for the day. Thank you for the help. There must be another problem as you stated